How to aggregate multiple tables in one request in high load system
I need to have send response to client apps:
{
"success": true,
"error": null,
"data": 
    {
        "rate_count": 3000,
        "review_count": 3000,
        "review_formatted": "3K",
        "rate_avg":4.5,
        "customer_state": 
        {
            "state": 0 ,
            "items":[
                123598800,
                123598800,
            ]
        },
        "reviews":
             [
                    {
                       "feedback": "Good shop",
                       "rating": "3 star",
                       "ordered_items": "Coca cola",
                       "customer_name": "john",
                       "review_tags": ["Nice shop","Good service"],
                       "created_at": "2024-09-03 14:00:39"
                    },
             ]
    }

}
1 part: rate_count, review_count, review_formatted, reate_avg can be wrapped from the Rate and Review tables
2 part: customer state is from customer_product_state table
3 part: reviews from Reviews table.
My db is on Postgres, for cache we can use redis and memory cache .
Note for in memory cache:
Should be careful that app is running on kubernetes with multiple instances. It is OK, to store 1 part of response in memory with 3 min expiration, since it is not critical to see averages after 3 min
This is high load system, I can't pressure postgres since there will be a lots of requests, that's why using cache would be good
So, my question is how can I store them on cache and make it very performant? It would be good to show some code examples

It seems like your question is asking for a solution rather than focusing on a problem. Is there a current setup? It would be good to show some code examples.

You mean load all the data from the database and generate it as the json and put it inside a cache like redis?
